# how to compare 2 images using sikuli webdriver?

Tags: sikuli

Currently, I am integrating Sikuli with Selenium and also working automating maps. I would like to compare two images are similar or not. I have taken screenshot of an image I am expecting to present in map. Pls suggest Sikuli script for comparing 2 images. Thank you.

Comment: so you want to compare a screenshot of the map with the actual map? What map is it? google-maps? Inside a webbrowser? Give me some more details.

Comment: Yes absolutely. it is a kind of Google map inside a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find out if the screenshot is found inside your browser window, you can use:

```
try:
   find("screenshot.jpg");
   popup("Found");
except:
   popup("Not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to sting and then compare both image. like this

```
     ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
    URL imageURL = new URL("img1 url here");

    Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget("imageURL");
    ScreenRegion r = s.wait(imageTarget,8000);


    Canvas canvas = new DesktopCanvas();
    canvas.addLabel(r, keyword).display(3);
    String c1= canvas.toString(); 

    ScreenRegion s1 = new DesktopScreenRegion();
    URL imageURL1 = new URL("img2 url here");

    Target imageTarget1 = new ImageTarget(imageURL1);
    ScreenRegion r1 = s1.wait(imageTarget1,8000);


    Canvas canvas1 = new DesktopCanvas();
    canvas1.addLabel(r1, keyword).display(3);
    String c2= canvas.toString(); 


    if(C1==C2){ 
      return true;
        }else{
    return false;
           }
```

if you didn't got the point let me know.
Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you Know.